# Viewing using computer Chrome a HTML page downloaded on Arndroid Chrome

Tags: chrome-for-android

I save webpages for offline reading by opening the three-dot menu icon and tapping the download icon up top, which will download a version of the page. I also take regular backups on USB drives.

Now if I wish to view these HTML pages on my computer's Chrome browser, how do I do the same?

These files do not have any file extension. I tried adding .htm to them and then trying to open but was not successful.

All help is sincerely appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Apparently, [this Chrome's behavior doesn't seem to be global](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/247025/android-chrome-saving-web-page-without-mhtml-extension#comment331203_247025). So, to determine the line, is it okay for you to mention the device model and Android version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome for Android saves a webpage in [MHTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML) format. It doesn't append the extension in the filename though, hence, the problem in opening it in Chrome on PC. Opening such a file in Chrome on PC without correct extension makes Chrome load the content of the webpage in plain text instead.

Appending `.mhtml` or `.mht` as extension to the filename and then opening the webpage in Chrome on PC should work.