# Android Chrome saving web page without MHTML extension

Tags: chrome-for-android

Just got a Pixel 6 Pro, Android 12. Whenever I save a web page using the 3-dot menu, download web page arrow, the file is being saved with no extension.

It has always been saved as .mhtml on previous phones. I have to rename them to add the .mhtml extension. I tried Chrome and Chrome Beta. I looked at the files with two different file managers.

Any ideas?

Comment: I just tried it, the file may have no file extension but the content is mhtml (RFC 2557 multipart file similar to an e-mail containing multiple files).

Comment: Hi Robert. Thanks for the reply. Yes - when the mhtml extension is added, the file opens correctly with File Manager. Otherwise it doesn't know what to do with it.

Comment: I just tried on both Nexus 5, Lineage OS 14.1 (Android 7.1) and Pixel 3a, Android 12 on both Chrome 102. Nexus 5 still saved with extension while Pixel 3a didn't. I'd guess there's a different behavior on Chrome itself, possibly depending on the Android version, for unclear reasons...

Comment: This problem has existed for some time. See [Viewing using computer Chrome a HTML page downloaded on Arndroid Chrome](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/236357/96277)

Comment: Hi All - Thanks for the responses. My previous phone (Pixel 3A XL, Android 9) appended the MHTML extension correctly. Any ideas on what changed (Chrome, phone, or OS)?